# View SMTP traffic from IIS7

Tags: iis-7, smtp, windows-server-2008, virus

I have a situation where a 2008 server with IIS7 has been application level compromised and is sending spam from port 25. We have ran a virus scan and removed the infected files yet the spam is still being sent.

We know the spam is coming from a local file as the firewall has port 25 blocked inbound and the SMTP log is showing all requests appearing from the local server.  We have ran a LogParser scan of the sites (which there are many) for any POST data to files on the server but the results all look genuine.  The PID sending the data on port 25 is simply inetinfo.exe so this isn't much use either.

I would like to identify what file is sending this e-mail, can anyone think of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you shut down the smtp server under properties for local outbound? meaning 127. etc...? also, have you looked in the que folder under inetpub to see if the offending message is in there? In some cases a file can change the remote server on smtp in IIS to send via  aproxy or some other service so it would ignore your scans.

in addition, not all mail has to use port 25 to send emails. it can hit any port if the creator tells it to.

Comment: We have checked that relaying is only for 127.0.0.1 and all the security settings look ok. 

We have not checked the queue folder so that is something to look at.

I can see the e-mail being sent through the SMTP logs of IIS so it is definitely port 25.

Ideally we'd like a way to identify which file is still achieving this mail being sent.